# Newtonsoft - JsonProperty name as a variable

Tags: json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft and I have this JSON property:

```
[JsonProperty("br")]
public Market Market { get; set; }
```

But I want to set the name of the property as a variable, like this:

```
string market = TestContext.Parameters["market"];
[JsonProperty(market)]
public Market Market { get; set; }
```

There is any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `PropertyName` in JSON

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "market")]
public Market Market { get; set; }
```

Comment: but market will have different names that I pass as a parameter. TestContext.Parameters["market"] could return "br", "ar", "es", ...

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433732/dynamically-change-the-json-property-name-and-serialize