# How to set Key name dynamically while serializing class object to JSON string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, type-conversion

Suppose I am having one class like -

```
public class Test
{
   public int id { get; set; } 
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Normal JSON conversion will output like **{"id":1,"name":"Souvik"}**

If I Put JsonProperty attribute like below in properties, output will be - **{"studentId":1,"studentname":"Souvik"}**

```
public class Test
{ 
  [JsonProperty("studentId")]
  public int id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("studentname")]
  public string name { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't want to set this hardcoded name of JsonProperty on id, name property of class and want to set these dynamically. How Can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? Can you show some usage? How dynamically you want to change the property names, what is the use case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433732/dynamically-change-the-json-property-name-and-serialize/44435284

Comment: I want to set the JsonProperty name dynamically, meaning output may be like  {"id":1,"name":"Souvik"}  / {"FullID":1,"Fullname":"Souvik"} / anything like this. Noticed that Key name in JSON output is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve but you can for example add properties as entries to `Dictionary<string, string>`, and serialize it:

```
var test = new Test
{
    id = 1,
    name = "test"
};
var x = new Dictionary<string, object>();
x.Add("studentId", test.id); // dynamically build the key  
x.Add("studentName", test.name); // dynamically build the key 
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)); // prints "{"studentId":1,"studentName":"test"}"
```

Comment: This one helped me. thank you